# NavigationSplitView: using view for sidebar and show selected element in detail

Tags: swiftui

I struggle to replace NavigationStack with NavigationSplitView. I want to use the list for the sidebar from the ItemListView (works perfectly):

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ItemSplitView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context

    @State private var sortOrder = SortOrder.title
    @State private var filter = ""
    
    @State private var selectedItem: Item? = nil
    
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            // Sidebar (List of items)
            ItemList(sortOrder: sortOrder, filterString: filter)
                .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
                .navigationTitle("Items")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem (placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                        Picker("", selection: $sortOrder) {
                            ForEach(SortOrder.allCases) { sortOrder in
                                Text("Sort by \(sortOrder.rawValue)").tag(sortOrder)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .searchable(text: $filter, prompt: Text("full text search"))
                .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, onDismiss: {
                    ItemListView()
                },  content: {
                    UserPropertiesScreen(isPresented: self.$isPresented)
                })
        } detail: {
            // Content view (EditItemView for selected item)
            if let selectedItem = selectedItem {
                EditItemView(item: selectedItem, navigationPath: $path)
            } else {
                Text("Select an item from the sidebar")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here the editItemView:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct EditItemView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    @Bindable var item: Item
    @Binding var navigationPath: NavigationPath
    
    //let item: Item
    
    @State private var title = ""
    @State private var desc = ""

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            VStack {
                Section {
                    LabeledContent {
                        TextField("", text:$title)
                    } label: {
                        Text("Title").foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                    }
                    TextEditor(text:$desc)
                }
            }

            Button(action: {
                dismiss()
            }) {
                HStack{
                    Text("Cancel").font(.body)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("MoRed3"))
                    Image(systemName: "xmark.circle").font(.body)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("MoRed3"))
                }
                .padding (.vertical)
            }
        }


        .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
            dismiss()
        }) {
            Text("Cancel").font(.body)
            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle").font(.body)
        })

        var changed: Bool {
            title != item.title
        }
    }
}
```

If an item from the list (ItemList) is tapped, the detail of the item isn't shown in the EditItemView in the detail section. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] - some code that I can directly paste into a new Xcode project and reproduce the problem.

Comment: If the problem is with displaying `EditItemView` why not show the code for it.
Note, you don't need use and pass the `NavigationPath` anymore. 
Note also,  the `onDismiss` in `.sheet(...., onDismiss: {  ItemListView() ` looks very suspicious. 
In addition, you don't set `selectedItem` to anything. 
See this link [NavigationSplitView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationsplitview)  for how to use `NavigationSplitView`

Comment: The detail view is dependent on the state variable `selectedItem`, but this isn't being set anywhere. It probably needs to be passed as a binding to `ItemList`.

Comment: Not related but navigationBarItems was deprecated years ago, you should use toolbar